# ASP.NET MVC: Redirect after SetAuthCookie redirects to login page again

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

Q/A - a gotcha I ran into today.

After setting the forms cookie and redirecting, the login pages loads again. However, if I ignore the second login page and just go to a URL that's "behind the authorize barrier", it renders, so the cookie has worked. It just seems to take two requests to 'stick'. Why?

Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TempLogin(Models.Authentication.SimpleLoginModel loginModel, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (this.ValidateTempSecret(loginModel.Secret))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("tempuser", false);

                if (returnUrl.IsNotNullOrWhitespace())
                {
                    Redirect(returnUrl);
                }                    
                else
                {
                    Redirect(FormsAuthentication.DefaultUrl);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.ModelState.AddModelError("secret", "The password is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        return View();            
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling `return Redirect(...` so the action is not returning but falling through to render the login view again! Doh.